# the 'Color Animations plugin' doesn't work on webkit(safari chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery

the Color Animations doesn't wokr on webkit(safari chrome)

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.color.js">s</script>
$('#start').animate({ 'backgroundColor':'yellow' }, 1000,'linear', function() {
        })
```

it is works well on firefox

why ?

thanks

---

the answer is background,look next code

and you will be find a is not run,and b is ok(in safari and chrome):

```
<dl id=a style="width:100px;height:100px;">

</dl>
<dl id=b style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#fff">

</dl>
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#a,#b').animate({ backgroundColor: "orange" }, 1000)
.animate({ backgroundColor: "yellow" }, 1000)
.animate({ backgroundColor: "green" }, 1000)
</script>
```

Comment: you code example doesn't look complete.

Comment: Ignore my answer for the moment. Does the demo site work on your version of Chrome? 

http://dev.jquery.com/~john/ticket/fx-rewrite2/

Comment: Okay, new answer is up. Let me know if helps.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I'm noticing from your example:

First, you have a stray letter `s` in your script tag. Not sure if that's in your code or how various browsers handle it.

Second, you don't actually have the body of the script wrapped in any kind of `document.ready` type wrapper, and you don't have the function tied to an event handler, which means that, at least with what you are showing us, the script is maybe loaded before the document is ready, it isn't seeing the `#start` element, so it just never does anything.